# I have a seemingly simple Pig generate and then filter issue

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to run a simple Pig script on a simple csv file and I can not get FILTER to do what I want. I have a test.csv file that looks like this:

```
john,12,44,,0
bob,14,56,5,7
dave,13,40,5,5
jill,8,,,6
```

Here is my script that does not work:

```
people = LOAD 'hdfs:/whatever/test.csv' using PigStorage(',');
data = FOREACH people GENERATE $0 AS name:chararray, $1 AS first:int, $4 AS second:int;
filtered = FILTER data BY first == 13;
DUMP filtered;
```

When I dump data, everything looks good. I get the name and the first and last integer as expected. When I describe the data, everything looks good:

```
data: {name: bytearray,first: int,second: int}
```

When I try and filter out data by the first value being 13, I get nothing. DUMP filtered simply returns nothing. Oddly enough, if I change it to first > 13, then all "rows" will print out.

However, this script works:

```
peopletwo = LOAD 'hdfs:/whatever/test.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:int,f4:int,f5:int);
datatwo = FOREACH peopletwo GENERATE $0 AS name:chararray, $1 AS first:int, $4 AS second:int;
filteredtwo = FILTER datatwo BY first == 13;
DUMP filteredtwo;
```

What is the difference between filteredtwo and filtered (or data and datatwo for that matter)? I want to know why the new relation obtained using GENERATE (i.e. data) won't filter in the first script as one would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the datatype in the load itself.See below

```
people = LOAD 'test5.csv' USING PigStorage(',') as (f1:chararray,f2:int,f3:int,f4:int,f5:int);
filtered = FILTER people BY f2 == 13;
DUMP filtered;
```

**Output**

[image: equals]

Changing the filter to use > gives

```
filtered = FILTER people BY f2 > 13;
```

**Output**

[image: greater]

**EDIT**

When converting from bytearray you will have to explicitly cast the value of the fields in the FOREACH.This works.

```
people = LOAD 'test5.csv' USING PigStorage(','); 
data = FOREACH people GENERATE $0 AS name:chararray,(int)$1 AS f1,(int)$4 AS f2;
filtered = FILTER data BY f1 == 13;
DUMP filtered;
```

Comment: This does solve the exact problem I posed but I guess my question was more generic than that. Why does the generated relation not work with the filter? That is really what I am interested in knowing.

Comment: What is your version of Pig? Source:http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch04.html#schemas It should be noted that in Pig 0.8 and earlier, much of this runtime adaption code was shaky and often failed. In 0.9, much of this has been fixed. But if you are using an older version of Pig, you might need to cast the data explicitly to get the right results.

Comment: I am using version 0.15.0. It does feel like some kind of schema failure since the first > 13 returns all results in the first script. It's as if the values aren't getting the right integer values for some reason. It's a very odd error that has been bothering me for most of the day. Like you said, the fix is to just provide a schema for the initial load but I'd rather not be forced into doing that.

Comment: @John I've edited the script to include explicit cast.See here for more explanation on CASTS and bytearray.http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch04.html#casts  When you don't specify the data type the load function loads the fields as bytearray and when you don't explicitly cast into int in FOREACH it can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Well done my friend. I spent quite a while trying to track down the bug and then when I did track it down, it made no sense. Usually we have schemas for our original loads but for this instance we did not. I tried so many variants of casts and whatnot it was annoying. In the end, I just added a schema to the original load and it worked fine but I really wanted to know why this generate/filter thing wasn't working. All is well now, thanks much for your help.